# Dot (.) usage in Latin Words?

Tags: punctuation, latin

The question is short and simple.

Say I use `i.e.` in my formal publication. Which is correct?

> ... by the interior landmarks, i.e. elevators and escalators.

Or

> ... by the interior landmarks, i.e.**,** elevators and escalators.

What about `e.g.`? Is it always followed by a `,`?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/should-there-be-a-comma-after-i-e and
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/should-i-always-use-a-comma-after-e-g-or-i-e

Comment: Personally I always prefer ie. and eg. - the extra dot just looks messy IMHO and who cares if the original Latin is 2 words?  The end dot still shows that it's a phrase abbreviation.

Comment: Please search the site before asking. Please also make sure that the title of your question actually matches the question.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Which exactly is your question? Your title asks one question - which does appear to be answered by the 'duplicate' question. But your question text asks a *different* question - which *is* answered by the linked questions.

Comment: I'd simply replace the second period with a comma; i.e, I would punctuate it like this. But then, I'm a licensed professional.

Comment: I'd simply not use periods with these abbreviations; ie, I would punctuate it like this. But then, I read a licensed professional saying: 'It is not safe, nor trouble-free, to follow the rules. They are idiotic and describe nothing. Pay no attention to them.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp) recommends using a semicolon before and a comma after *that is*, *for example*, *i.e.*, and *e.g.* For example,

> You will need writing materials; e.g., pens and pencils.

Comment: Interesting Jasper. Is that actually used? Frankly, I don't think I have seen much of that (";"). Isn't more common just the "," ?